# running pythoncode in background? [Debian 10]

Tags: python, debian, discord

I just worte a simple Discordbot in python & now i'd like to run it on my Debian10 Server.
But the terminal wont be opend the whole time, so i need something like **Screen** (Or is it even possible to use screen for this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Screen is possible, but creating a service in systemd is likely the best route.

Comment: Thanks for your response, could u gimme a small tip how it would work?

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)